# GET http://localhost:8080/index.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Tags: javascript, spring-boot, mustache

I couldnt find solution for my issue. I'm following book Learning Spring Boot 3.0 - Third Edition. Im at chapter 2, but struggle to get everything to work properly.
Im using mustache and try to load js modules, but get 404 on getting index.js when I make a call on http://localhost:8080/react

> GET http://localhost:8080/index.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Here is the whole code: https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Learning-Spring-Boot-3.0-Third-Edition/tree/main/ch2
This is source code of the book, and the orginal code has the issue aswell.

Can anyone help me identify why I get 404? This is blocker for me, I dont want to continue untill I resolve the issue.

Comment: Please read [Something on my web site doesn't work. Can I just paste a link to it?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it). Questions that depend on external resources to be understood become useless when the external resource goes away or is fixed. Create a [MCVE] and put it in **the question itself** instead. Stackoverflow does support [inline live demos](https://stackoverflow.blog/2014/09/16/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/)

Comment: I don't know what program you're using but i do know normal file location referencing.  That file is apparently in a javascript subdirectly.  Try changing this line <script type="module" src="index.js"></script> to have the javascript folder in it.